# How can i pass data from promise to props in react

Tags: reactjs, promise

I'm new to react and I want to pass my data from my securestore to props. But I don't now how to correctly handle the promise function and extract the data of it.

When I pass the data like this, my object is undefined.

Here is my code.

```
const Authenticate = () => {
  
    //const [deviceId, setDeviceId] = useState("");
    //SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("device_id").then((reject) => {
    //});

    //const resp = {code : 3, expositions : 5}

    SecureStore.getItemAsync("device_id").then((response) => {
      //setDeviceId({"id" : response});
      console.log("stored id : " + response);
      //let resp = sendId({'id' : response})
      test(response);
    }
);

      function test (info){
        return info;
      }

      return (
        <Expositions infections={test()}/>
      );
};
export default Authenticate;
```

Answer (score 2):

you should really read [this](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

```
const Authenticate = () => {
  
    const [myStuff, setMyStuff] = useState();
    
    //this will be executed on mount
    useEffect(()=>{
      SecureStore.getItemAsync("device_id").then((response) => {
         setMyStuff(response)
        }
      );
    },[])
      
   console.log(myStuff) 
 }
```

on first render `myStuff` is `undefined`, then after fetching your data, `setMyStuff` will trigger a new render and you'll see the updated data

Comment: My secureStore.getItemAsync function is not called within useEffect

Comment: i've not enough information dude, if you put a log before and after fetching your data you' ll see that the code is being called. But i don't know what SecureStore is , are you sure you are fetching data correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use react state hook to store the data provided by promise and then pass the state to the rendered jsx.